# Does neo4j by default filter circular relationships in match clause

Tags: neo4j, cypher

If I have a a relationship between nodes A and B as A-[:knows]->B the following query returns nothing

```
MATCH (A)-[:knows]-(B)-[:knows]-(A) return *;
```

Whereas a query with explicit 'with' works

```
MATCH (A)-[:knows]-(B) with B MATCH (B)-[:knows]-(A) return *;
```

Why is this behavior? Why wouldn't the first query return anything?
The behavior doesn't change even if I use relationship directions in the match query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside a pattern, Cypher will traverse only **ONCE** a relationship.

With your pattern `(A)-[r1:knows]-(B)-[r2:knows]-(A)`, `r1` **MUST** be different than `r2`.
So if you only have one relationship between `A` and `B`, this pattern will return nothing.

This behaviour is there to avoid cycles on queries.

Comment: Also, `MATCH (A)-[:knows]-(B)-[:knows]-(A)` (which uses non-directional relationships) does not even make much sense (aside from sometimes returning unexpected results). `MATCH (A)-[:knows]-(B)` or ``MATCH (B)-[:knows]-(A)` is more reasonable.

Comment: You are right that at first MATCH (A)-[:knows]-(B)-[:knows]-(A) doesn't make sense. However I have a function that takes 3 arguments and comes up with a query like MATCH (arg1)-[:knows]-(arg2)-[:knows]-(arg3) and could probably be called with arg1=A, arg2=B, arg3=A.
I was trying to avoid splitting the above match into two separate match statements with the use of an explicit 'with' clause.

I guess I will recheck if my caller itself could detect arg1=arg3 condition and do something different.